# Is pyarrow.Table good for long-term storage of pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, serialization, apache-arrow

Trying to come up with a solution for quick Pandas dataframes serialization and long-storage. Dataframe content is tabular, but provided by user, can be arbitrary, so might both completely text columns and completely numeric/boolean columns.

### Main goals are:

- Serialize dataframe as quickly as possible in order to dump it on disk.
- Use format, that i'll be able to load from disk later back into dataframe.
- Well, the least memory footprint of serialization and compact output file.

Have ran benchmarks comparing different serialization methods, including:

- Parquet: `df.to_parquet()`
- Feather: `df.to_feather()`
- JSON: `df.to_json()`
- CSV: `df.to_csv()`
- PyArrow: `pyarrow.default_serialization_context().serialize(df)`
- PyArrow.Table: `pyarrow.default_serialization_context().serialize(pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(df))`

Speed of serialization and memory footprint during that are probably biggest factors (read: get rid of data, dump it to disk asap).

Strangely in our benchmarks serializing `pyarrow.Table` seems the most balanced and quite fast.

### Questions:

1. Is there something I'm missing in understanding difference between serializing dataframe directly using PyArrow and serializing `pyarrow.Table`, Table shines in case dataframes mostly consists of strings, which is frequent in our cases.
2. Is `pyarrow.Table` a valid option for long-storage of dataframes? It seems to "just works", but mostly people just stick to Parquet or something else.
3. Parquet/Feather are as good as pyarrow.Table in terms of memory / storage size, but quite slower on half-text dataframes, (2-3x slower). Could I be doing something wrong?

In case of mixed-type dataframes JSON still seems like an option according to our benchmarks.

I can provide the numbers if needed.

Comment: I'd be happy to discuss this with you on the dev@arrow.apache.org mailing list. It's more of a discussion than a StackOverflow Q&A kind of thing

Comment: Thanks, @WesMcKinney, did as you suggested.